# I don't know what is different between " : " and " . " in css

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
 a:hover
 a:focus,
 a:active
 a.active {

      color: #fec503;
 }
```

And I don't know what is different between "a:active" and "a.active". So can someone explain to me?

Comment: Search for "css selectors" and read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html

Answer (score 1):

a:active would basically describe a anchor link that's active. With that style, your CSS would target all active links.

a.active is more specific. It targets an anchor tag that has a class of active.

For example: `<a href="www.example.com" class="active">`

For more information on CSS selectors, I recommend:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

First they are all [classes selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors),

":" is a Pseudo-class selector:
It references a state, eg. :active, :hover, :first-child, :empty etc.

"." is a class selector:
Use the class attribute in an element to assign the element to a named class

Answer (score 0):

`.` is referencing a class. For example, to change the color of a link with class "active" you would use the following

```
a.active {
    color: red;
}
```

`:` is referencing a state. For example, to alter the color of a link being hovered over you would:

```
a: hover {
    color: green;
}
```